# SQL parameter ':par' for Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cyhw.png)

Looking at this picture, my parameter deviceType is int, so using :deviceType is correct, but my deviceId is String, and I need to use 'deviceId', so it's wrong. Please ask Room how to escape single quotes'

I tried using , he couldn't

```
"SELECT  * from anitsnore_statistics where Device_type=:deviceType and deviceid =\':deviceId\'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want  `deviceId = 'whatever_device_passed'` (note not as per the required SQL to include the single quote) to be what is searched for.

That is the value that **deviceId** passed to the function holds, is `whatever_device_passed` (without single quotes) but you then want the value enclosed in single quotes, so that the value used for the comparison includes the single quote, then you could use:-

```
deviceid =''''||:deviceId||''''
```

- i.e. 2 quotes inside a text value (so the resolved value is a single quote) concatendated with the passed deviceid (which will be in quotes) concatenate again with the single quote. So you have `deviceid = 'whatever_device_passed'` as the fully resolved value (i.e. the single quotes are part of the value being compared).

However, if you are just searching for the passed deviceId then deviceid =:deviceId will suffice. That is Room in handling the passed value will properly enclose the value in single quotes (actually it is the SQLite parameter binding that encloses the value in the single quotes).

- *are you sure this is not actually what you want? (rhetorical)*

An alternative would be to include the single quotes would be to include the single quotes in the deviceId value passed to the function. In which case the SQLite binding will properly enclose the single quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with my difficulty.   
I tried deviceid =:deviceId, as you said it is OK .  
like this "SELECT  * from anitsnore_statistics where Device_type=:deviceType and deviceid =:deviceId"

Comment: @Yung if you found the answer helpful and the best answer, please tick the answer. You will gain experience in doing so and also indicate to others that the answer can be of help. P.S. Glad to be of help.

Comment: @Yung and then you will often get an up vote for the question and more experience, as has happened.